# How to add extra attribute to stylesheet link?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css, customization

Following [Keith Clarks advice](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/loading-css-without-blocking-render/), i'd like to load my fonts asynchronously. I try to achieve that by adding:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', URI . '/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
wp_style_add_data( 'font-awesome', 'onload', 'if(media!=\'all\')media=\'all\'');
```

to my `scripts.php` file, but apparently this argument is not well taken by that function, because there is no onload attribute. How properly can I do that in WordPress?

Answer (score 6):

We can use [`style_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/) filter to filter the link that is being output.

Here is the filter:

```
$tag = apply_filters( 'style_loader_tag', "<link rel='$rel' id='$handle-css' $title href='$href' type='text/css' media='$media' />\n", $handle, $href, $media);
```

Here the link $handle for which you want to add attribute is **`font-awesome`** so if the handle, so you can replace `font-awesome-css` with extra info.

```
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'wpse_231597_style_loader_tag');

function wpse_231597_style_loader_tag($tag){

    $tag = preg_replace("/id='font-awesome-css'/", "id='font-awesome-css' online=\"if(media!='all')media='all'\"", $tag);

    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! This seems rather like a workaround, doesn't it? Which i did (dirtier i guess) by adding link when theme specific stylesheet is added. I was thinking about something more reusable, like defining ```enqueue_async_style``` function, with no success yet.

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct filter to add an extra attribute without doing dirty job

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be deferring more than one stylesheet, I've found this approach to be fairly reusable.

1. Put this somewhere:

```php
function _changeme_defer_css( $html, $handle ) {

    $deferred_stylesheets = apply_filters( 'changeme_deferred_stylesheets', array() );

    if ( in_array( $handle, $deferred_stylesheets, true ) ) {
        return str_replace( 'media=\'all\'', 'media="print" onload="this.media=\'all\'"', $html );
    } else {
        return $html;
    }

}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', '_changeme_defer_css', 10, 2 );
```

2. Load your font as you normally would:

```php
function _changeme_load_font_awesome() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', URI . '/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
}
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_changeme_load_font_awesome' );
```

3. Defer it like so:

```php
add_filter( 'changeme_deferred_stylesheets', function( $handles ) {
    $handles[] = 'font-awesome';
    return $handles;
}, 10, 1 );
```

4. If you want to make sure it only impacts the public-facing side of your site, and not `wp-admin`, you could add a check for `! is_admin()` as well (especially for commonly-used libraries like `Font Awesome` or `Select2`):

```php
add_filter( 'changeme_deferred_stylesheets', function( $handles ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $handles[] = 'font-awesome';
    }
    return $handles;
}, 10, 1 );
```

I also updated the `onload` approach based on Scott Jehl's [The Simplest Way to Load CSS Asynchronously](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/) (2019) but if you're going to do this, you may also want to read the "Async CSS" passage from Harry Roberts's [The Fastest Google Fonts](https://csswizardry.com/2020/05/the-fastest-google-fonts/) (2020) to see why he recommends preloading as well.

Answer (score 2):

I really understand both of you, but I would like to point out that following [Keith Clark's advice](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/loading-css-without-blocking-render/) is just following another bad practice. I also understand that this is asked and answered in 2016 and that most things change for better or worse.

If you need to delay a stylesheet, then I would recommend you the following:

```
// I use get_footer to put my stylesheets in the footer
function add_footer_styles() {
    // Example loading external stylesheet, could be used in both a theme and/or plugin
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-5', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css', array(), null );

    // Example theme
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-5', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/fontawesome.min.css' ), array(), null );

    // Example plugin
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-5', plugins_url( '/assets/css/fontawesome.min.css', __FILE__ ), array(), null );
};
add_action( 'get_footer', 'add_footer_styles' );
```

**[Integrity and crossorigin](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/)**
If you add Font Awesome 5 externally I would also recommend using [integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) and [crossorigin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), see my other answer for a more detailed take on adding attributes: [How to add crossorigin and integrity to wp_register_style? (Font Awesome 5)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/317035/how-to-add-crossorigin-and-integrity-to-wp-register-style-font-awesome-5)

```
function add_font_awesome_5_cdn_attributes( $html, $handle ) {
    if ( 'font-awesome-5' === $handle ) {
        return str_replace( "media='all'", "media='all' integrity='sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU' crossorigin='anonymous'", $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'add_font_awesome_5_cdn_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: +1 for using $handle